# Estimate steel ball collision time?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration

Assume there're two usual small steel balls (for example, $d=0.1$ m) occurred a collision with characteristic speed (for example, $\Delta v=0.1$ m/s). Could you please estimate the order of magnitude of collision time in the procedure?

I'm just curious about it. Thanks a lot.

---

Edit: This is not a homework/exercise... I noticed this question when someone said "When a standing hard disk fell on the table, the $a$ will be about 350g and the hard disk may be damaged". What I really want is the estimated collision time rather than how to calculate $a$ from $\Delta t$.

Comment: I guess these are hollow balls?  A solid ball of steel 0.1 m in diameter weighs a sight more than 0.2 kg.

Comment: fixed the bug...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://www.physics.emory.edu/faculty/brody/Advanced%20Lab/Advanced-Lab-Elasticity3.pdf

They use the Hertz impact theory and derive the time of a collision of a ball with a plate. I don't think this time will be much different from the time of collision of two balls in view of symmetry considerations (which are not totally convincing, I admit).

Their result (they assume, in particular, that the Poisson ratio is 0.3):
$$\tau=6.46 \rho^{2/5}\frac{R}{U_0^{1/5}E^{2/5}},$$

where $\tau$ is the total time of the contact, $U_0$ is the ball velocity before the collision, $\rho$ is the density, $R$ is the radius of the ball, $E$ is the elasticity modulus.

EDIT (1/20/18): for $U_0$=0.1 m/s, $R$=0.05 m, $\rho$=7850 kg/m^3, $E$=209 GPa one obtains $\tau\approx$0.55 ms.

Answer (score 0):

We know momentum will be conserved. So assuming that the balls have identical speeds with respect to the ground, each ball will begin with initial momentum $p\sim 0.02$ kg m/s.

If this is an elastic collision (reasonable approximation for steel balls), then kinetic energy would be conserved as well, and we may state that after the collision, the balls will each have the same speed.

Using impulse ($\vec{J}=\vec{F}_{avg}\Delta t = \Delta \vec{p}$), the change in momentum of one ball would be $p\sim 0.04$ kg m/s.

If we assume that the collision lasts for $\sim 0.01$ sec, we find $\vec{F}_{avg} = \frac{\Delta \vec{p}}{\Delta t}\sim \frac{0.04}{0.01} = 4$ N, which with a mass of 0.2 kg implies an acceleration of 20 m/s$^2$.

(Assuming the collision lasted 0.01 sec seems reasonable to me, but maybe it would be more like 0.05 or 0.1 second long.)

Comment: what I really want is the estimated usual collision time...

Comment: ah, that's very different than estimate of acceleration

Comment: and that's difficult, I think...

Comment: Maybe something along the lines of looking into the compressibility of steel (which would be a $\Delta x$), and you know $\Delta v$, this can give you an estimation of $a$ (using equations of 1-D motion). If you can estimate $a$, then you might be able to estimate t again using impulse?